# Training time increases dramatically within just a few iterations using tensorflow GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I am training a CNN AlexNet model on a quite large dataset (DeepFashion) containing around 300,000 images. I resize the images to 96x96x3 and I am using GPU nvidia tesla K80 and 4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory on GCP (google cloud). The thing is that when I start the training it runs really well for about 500 iterations but then speed dramatically drops. The GPU utilization in the start is around 50% but then drops to 0-7%. I really don't know what might be causing this.

Test set is 209,222 images
Val set is 40,000 images
train set is 40,000 images

Below is my simple code snippet, does anyone have any idea what can be causing this dramatic drop in computation speed and how I can fix it?

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    os.path.join(dataset_path, 'train'),
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=seed,
    image_size=(96, 96),
    batch_size=64)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    os.path.join(dataset_path, 'val'),
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=seed,
    image_size=(96, 96),
    batch_size=64)


test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    os.path.join(dataset_path, 'test'),
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=seed,
    image_size=(96, 96),
    batch_size=64)



AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)



model = get_uncompiled_AlexNet(img_width=96, img_height=96, img_channel=3, num_classes=46)


model_optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)


model_metrics_top_3 = tf.keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=3, name='top_3_accuracy')
model_metrics_top_5 = tf.keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=5, name='top_5_accuracy')


model.compile(
    loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
    optimizer=model_optimizer, 
    metrics=["accuracy", model_metrics_top_3, model_metrics_top_5])

history = model.fit(
    train_ds, 
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=10)
```

Comment: Does the slowdown take place during the first epoch, on the switch to the second, or a bit later? From the numbers you provided it is not clear.

Comment: The slowdown takes place during the first epoch. With batch size of 64 one epoch is around 3000 iterations and the slowdown is after the first 300-800 iterations, it varies slightly..

Comment: Have you checked free ram size? It may be that ram becomes full and TF cannot cache data into the memory.

Comment: I mean the ram is 15GB so it should not be a problem, i think. Do you mean check the free ram while running the training?

Comment: I checked the free ram while running the training and approx. 10GB is free